# How to printscreen a big treeview in a windows app?

Tags: screen-capture, print-screen

I have an app that I would like to send the screenshot of all selected options to the developer, but the options are in a huge treeview...

**Is there a trick to easily printscreen it**, like capture webpages do for long pages (they scroll it automatically)...

app with the tree view that I wanted to do the printscreen:

[image]

all I want is what's inside the treeview. I did several shots and "glue" them in Fireworks, but Adobe Fireworks **max height is around 6000px** and this is way more...

image example: http://s6.postimg.org/xqfpd92g1/Untitled_1.png

Comment: evidently not, maybe it should be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I screen capture a scrolling region?

[ScreenshotCaptor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) will capture scrolling regions.

---

> Screenshot Captor is a best-in-class tool for grabbing, manipulating,
>   annotating, and sharing screenshots. It's different from other
>   screenshot utilities in several notable ways:
>
> - Optimized for taking lots of screenshots with minimal intervention; stays out of your way until you need it.
> - Super easy to add and edit callout arrows and text boxes.
> - Easy automatic or on-demand uploading of screenshots to image hosting services; easy emailing of screenshots to your friends and
>     colleagues.
> - Take snapshots from webcams; record video with the ESR addon.
> - New optional quick-capture docking bar and post-capture action dialog.
> - Full set of scanner acquisition tools and scanner image correction.
> - Perfect capture of Windows 7 partial transparency effects.
> - **The most powerful scrolling capture tool in the field.**
> - Great special effects, including automatic active window enhancement, ragged edge splicing, pixelation, smart text removal, and
>     many more.
> - Smart autonaming of files, easy renaming and format conversion; automatic image file versioning.
> - Ability to embed textual comments in files or add attractive captions to images and printouts.
> - Unsurpassed multi-monitor support and lots of capture modes: Multimon (multiple monitors), Desktop, Active Window, Region, Windows
>     Object, Scrolling Capture. Each mode has a customizable hotkey for
>     quick access.
> - Unsurpassed support for 3rd party user configurable tools, including file browsers and image editors; extend the program to do
>     whatever you need by interfacing it with other programs.
> - Sidebar thumbnail file browser provides full shell operations, drag and drop support, and right-click actions on screenshots.
> - Deluxe thumbnail maker and watermarker.

[Screenshot Captor 3 - Window Object and Scrolling Capture Screencast Videos](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=29821)

License: Freeware

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [ScreenshotCaptor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

I have been using it for some years - it is a very useful program, particularly for writing documentation or training material, as you can annotate the screenshots as well.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't do it out-of-the-box, even after saw the videos... so I've posted a [message in their own forum](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=40111.new#new) I hope they will be able to help me...